# Not sure why a certain way of increment doesn't work in Array.reduce() method

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a problem like this there I have an array of objects and I try to use Array.reduce() to count all the numbers of the different types into a new object:

```
var desks = [
  { type: 'sitting' },
  { type: 'standing' },
  { type: 'sitting' },
  { type: 'sitting' },
  { type: 'standing' }
];

var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(curr.type === "sitting") {
    return {sitting: ++prev.sitting, standing: prev.standing};
  }

  if(curr.type === "standing") {
      return {sitting: prev.sitting, standing: ++prev.standing};
  }
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

The above example works and everything increments perfectly. Yet, when I switch the `++` to the right side (where I usually place it to increment a value), the function returns `NaN`.

```
var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(curr.type === "sitting") {
    return {sitting: prev.sitting++, standing: prev.standing};
  }

  if(curr.type === "standing") {
      return {sitting: prev.sitting, standing: prev.standing++};
  }
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

Honestly, I have no idea what's going on here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: it should return  sitting: 0, standing: 0 when having post increment operator. I've checked in jsfiddle and it's  sitting: 0, standing: 0 rather than NaN

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42317158/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459444/difference-between-i-i-and-i-i-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with `Array.reduce()`. You just need to understand how [pre/post increment operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) works.

`Pre` increments before assigning value.
`Post` increments AFTER assigning value.

Answer (score 2):

you are returning a new object each time with the values you are assigning to `sitting` and `standing`.  So your increment/decrement is applied after the current value (0) is assigned.  When I ran this I got `{ sitting: 0, standing: 0 }` back and not NaN.

Changing `prev.standing++` to `prev.standing+=` should resolve your issue.

And actually, you may want to consider just mutating the original accumulator you provided in this scenario.  Renaming `prev` to `accumulator`, `acc`, or simply `a` might make this easier to reason about.

```
var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    if(curr.type === "sitting") {
        acc.sitting++
    }
    else if (curr.type === "standing") {
        acc.standing++;
    }
    return acc
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

or even better:

```
var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc[curr.type]++;
    return acc
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having different result due to `pre increment(++x)` and `post increement operator (x++)`. When using preincrement operator, it increments value and return incremented value where as in post increment operator, it returns value and increemtn the value.

So, when using post increment operator in your code :

```
var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(curr.type === "sitting") {
 // prev.sitting is returning value and then incrementing which makes sitting value always 0
    return {sitting: prev.sitting++, standing: prev.standing}; 
  }

  if(curr.type === "standing") {
          // prev.standing is returning value and then incrementing which makes standing value always 0
      return {sitting: prev.sitting, standing: prev.standing++};
  }
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

If you change your way of assigning and have post incrementing value before assigning, then it works as per your expectation

```
var deskTypes = desks.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(curr.type === "sitting") {

  prev.sitting++;// it returns and increments sitting value and hence it has incremented value
    return {sitting: prev.sitting, standing: prev.standing};
  }

  if(curr.type === "standing") {
  // it returns and increments standing value and hence it has incremented value
  prev.standing++;
      return {sitting: prev.sitting, standing: prev.standing};
  }
}, { sitting: 0, standing: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful

```
var i = 1;
alert(i++); // shows 1
alert(i); // shows 2
i = 1;
alert(++i); // shows 2
alert(i); // shows 2
```

In your example `prev.sitting` & `prev.standing` is initially zero. So `(prev.sitting)++` will be zero too