# Postfix and prefix increments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious about one thing. A little example in Javascript

```js
var a = 1;
a = a++;
console.log(a); // 1

var b = 1;
b = ++b;
console.log(b); // 2

var c = 1;
c += 1;
console.log(c); //2
```

I understand why it works this way in case `b` and `c`, but what about `a`?
At first the code makes an assignment `a = a`, the value stays the same actually, but then it should (as I see) make increment and increase value `a` per unit. But this not happening. Why?

Comment: I believe `a++` means increment a, but not assigned. Whereas `++b` is increment and assign. So at this point: `a = a++` a is incremented but assigned back to its original value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript i++ vs ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i)

Comment: You don't normally do `a = a++` or  `a = ++a`.  If you want to assign the return value of either `a++` or `++a` you wouldn't want to assign them to the value you're incrementing.

Comment: @Eddie No, it’s not about post- vs pre-increment. It’s about what `a = a++;` means and does.

Comment: Don't just base it on the title alone. The answers on the post also answers this post. @Xufox

Comment: @Eddie Which one? I don’t see anything there that explains something like `a = a++;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867888/2930661 @Xufox

Comment: @Eddie In that one, the incremented variables are assigned to _different_ variables. This question is about assigning back to the _same_ variable.

Comment: Big difference? Maybe you might include the answer is using variable `b` instead of `a` because those are a world of difference. Right? @Xufox

Comment: @Eddie Yes. There is a space for huge confusion for a beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between i = i++ and i = i + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459444/difference-between-i-i-and-i-i-1). This question has actually been asked quite often in other languages like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33783989/4642212) and [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7911776/4642212), but JS was a bit difficult to find.

Comment: Sure, If you think it is not a duplicate, then it is not. That why it take 5 votes to close (if you are not gold badge). But i think it is. No need to convince me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> var a = 1;
> a = a++;
> ```

1. `1` is assigned to `a`
2. `a++` is evaluated as `1`
3. `a++` increments `a` to `2`
4. `a = {result of previous evaluation}` assigns the `1` to `a` so it is `1` again

> ```
> var b = 1;
> b = ++b;
> ```

1. `1` is assigned to `b`
2. `++b` increments `b` to `2`
3. `++b` is evaluated as `2`
4. `b = {result of previous evaluation}` assigns the `2` to `b` so it is `2` still

Answer (score 5):

That is how [post increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) works

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.

a = a++;

when a++ executes a is 2 and the expression returns 1 and a gets assigned to 1.

That is the reason you seeing the value before increment.

Note that if you don't assign back, you see the incremented value of `a`. You in short ovverriding the incremented value here by assigning it back.

```js
var a = 1;
a++;
console.log(a); // 1
```

Comment: your example actually returns 2 instead of 1. so the answer should be adapted `var a = 1;
a++;
console.log(a); // 2`

Answer (score 4):

It is rumored that to execute ++a, the value in memory increases and then returns. While for a++, first the value is stored in the created temporary variable, then the value of the primary variable is incremented and the value of the temporary variable is returned - thus the "expenses" for creating the temporary variable increase.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `a++` the return value is actually the original value. You’ve assigned the original value to `a` again.

Answer (score 2):

`a= a++` return the previous value of a **before increment** it's value.

you can just use `a++`

Answer (score 2):

The `a++` returns the value that *before* self-increase;
While the `++a` returns the value that *after* the self-increase;

so this is why when you call `a = a++`, a is equal to 1;

Answer (score 1):

The postfix operator returns the original value of a. 
So a is increased by the postfix ++ operator but then a is overwritten by assigning the return value of the operator, which is the value before incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `a` of `1` is temporary stored for assingment, then the increment takes place, `a` has now the value of `2` and then the assingmet of the former stored value happens.

```
a = a++;
```

is the same like

```
a = (temp = a, a++, temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1;
// Here a++ means a = a; then a = a + 1

a = a++; // so you are assign first step value inside a so thats way a = 1

console.log(a); // 1
```

means you are storing value that time when a++ is equal to a = a. You simply assigning the value of a and replacing the value.