# Assignment along with Post increment

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence, post-increment

I am a bit confused with the output. Tried in Javascript

```
var x = 1;
x = x++;
console.log(x); //Its output is 1
```

I was thinking it to be 2. because I am doing the print after the post-increment. Any views on it?

Comment: The *post* in *post-increment* means it first returns the current value and *post* that increments the variable. And you’re then assigning the returned value back to the variable…

Comment: it's because you're assigning the value of `x++` back into `x`. `x++` returns the value of `x` *before* the increment, while `++x` returns the value afterwards. That's the only difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postfix and prefix increments in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550526/postfix-and-prefix-increments-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order in which `x = x++` is executed is as follows:

- Old value of x is calculated (oldValue = 1)
- New value for x is calculated by adding 1 to old value (newValue = 2)
- New value is assigned to x. **At this point x becomes 2!**
- Old value is returned (return value is 1). This concludes the evaluation of `x++`
- The old value is assigned to x. **At this point x becomes 1**

The above rules [are described here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator). The rules indicate that `x` is incremented *before* assignment, not after.

Answer (score 6):

It's correct. The assignment goes first, then the incrementing.
Compare:

```js
var x = 1
var y = 1
x = x++
y = ++y

console.log(x, y)
```

Comment: So the post-increment never happened?

Comment: No, it did - its value was changed after the value was assigned, meaning that if `x = 5++`, then `x` is `5`, but the value was still increased by one, but not stored in `x`.

Comment: `x` was `2` for a brief moment between the expression `x++` having been evaluated and the assignment to `x =` having been completed…

Comment: Just refer to the official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic _If x is 3, then ++x sets x to 4 and returns 4, whereas x++ returns 3 and, only then, sets x to 4._ (the answer is in the part "**whereas x++ returns 3 and, only then, sets x to 4**")

Comment: You may imagine `++` like this: `function ++(x) { var tmp = x; x += 1; return tmp; }`…

Comment: "The assignment goes first, then the incrementing" is false