# curious double var case in javascript

Tags: javascript

Curious case in JavaScript where you get not exactly the most people would expect

```js
function test() {
  var v = 2;
  var v = v++;
  console.log(v);
}
test();
```

Why the `++` seems ignored here? at what point the ++ operation is executed?

"v++ increments v to 3 and returns 2"
what is the first, increment or return?

- if it increments first, the returned value should be "3"
- if it returns first 2, then after that increments, so the incremented value is 2 and v should be 3...

Comment: It's called a [postfix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#postfix_increment). It will assign and then increment. With `a = 0; b = a++;`, `a` will be 1 and `b` will be 0.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, I am aware, but here is rather interesting at what point is created the new variable

Comment: The second `var` is ignored.

Comment: @Pointy not at all

Comment: If you used `let` you would get a syntax error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but we don't use here let )

Comment: Yes, the second **declaration** is ignored, as the variable `v` was already declared in that scope. The *initialization* is not ignored, but the declaration is.

Comment: `var v = v++;` can be replaced with `v = v++;` without changing the behavior and result, if this helps you understanding the code. There is no _"the creation of the new "v""_.

Comment: at what point the `++` does work then? because it has any effect

Comment: `v` is initialized with `2`. `v++` increments `v` to `3` and returns `2`. `var v = v++;` assigns `2` to `v`.

Comment: The language specification says that the left-hand side is evaluated first, and then the right-hand side value is assigned to the left-hand side. The value of `v++` is the original value of `v`, so `v` ends up being 2.

Comment: I think in C and C++ such an expression might be explicitly undefined, so the runtime/compilation could do whatever it wants. In JavaScript, however, the behavior is explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `v` is initialized with `2`.
- The expression `v++` increments `v` to `3` and then returns `2`.
- The statement `var v = v++;` assigns `2` to `v` (overwrites the `3` in `v` with the `2` returned from `v++`).
- `console.log(v)` prints `2`

Comment: "v++ increments v to 3 and returns 2" what is the first, increment or return?

Comment: And the assignment of 2 to `v` happens *after* the right-hand side is completely evaluated, meaning that the increment of `v` to 3 happens *before* the assignment.

Comment: @Pointy `v++` increments `v` to `3` (first) and returns `2` (next).

Comment: @jabaa yes, exactly

Comment: @serge First increment, then `return`. `return` is always the last statement in a function or operation.

Comment: @Pointy I wasn't sure if you criticize my answer or gave clarification for serge.

Comment: I was trying to do both :) You answer is correct.

Comment: the answer of that one says "The assignment goes first, then the incrementing" https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515365/961631

Comment: @serge That's wrong. First, the right-hand side is completely evaluated and then the assignment happens.

Comment: this one really helped to understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515567/961631