# Incrementing using prefix and postfix

Tags: javascript, increment, post-increment

Can someone explain why the alert still shows 5 under postfix? I understand prefix identifies the last iteration to be falsy, but with postfix, it will still return i as 5.

```
// Prefix Code:
let i = 0;
while (++i < 5) {
    alert(i);
}
```

```
// Postfix code:
let i = 0;
while (i++ < 5) {
    alert(i);
}
```

There are different outputs. With prefix, the output is 1, 2, 3, 4

With postfix, the output is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

I'm unable to understand why the postfix output will return 5.

Comment: _Because it's post-_. You do the comparison (with 4), then increment (to 5), then alert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postfix and prefix increments in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550526/postfix-and-prefix-increments-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

> If used **postfix**, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments **and returns the value before incrementing**.

> If used **prefix**, with operator before operand (for example, ++x), the increment operator increments **and returns the value after incrementing**.

So in the postfix the comparison in the `while` condition is done with 4 but the value in that `alert` is 5